# On click buttons Scroll Div top of the window With increase height

Tags: javascript

In [Demo 01](http://jsfiddle.net/Jq4Vw/4/) You can see the Div is Scrolling top of the page with increase height.  And I need the same animation with click Buttons, like in [Demo 02](http://jsfiddle.net/mV353/).

```
$('.work-showcase').click(function(){
    $('.work-showcase').animate({height:'135px'}, 500);
  $(this).animate({height:'400px'}, 500,function() {  
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top });  
  });
    });
```

Comment: "*Div is Scrolling top of the page with increase height*".... it increases height but what you mean by "*scrolling top*" ? What's your issue?

Comment: If you see Demo 01, When You click Each Div ,increase div height and it scroll to top of the window. i need this animation happens with buttons for each Div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you want, but see if this Javascript works for you:

```
    var map = {
        "slice1": "#post1",
        "slice2": "#post2",
        "slice3": "#post3",
    }

    $('.clickable').click(function(){
        var postId = map[$(this).attr('id')];
        $('.post').animate({height:'50px'}, 500);
        $(postId).animate({height:'400px'}, 500,function() {  
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(postId).offset().top });  
        });
    });
```

See demo at http://jsfiddle.net/xCKPW/1/.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to do is have the animation and size change that you currently have get triggered when a button is clicked.

I also suspect you want the action to occur when the image is clicked.

In this case, move the animations into a separate function, and call that function onclick. 
 Here's your jsfiddle updated with buttons. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Jq4Vw/132/

```
$('.work-showcase, button').click(function(){
    moveAndResize($(this).index());
});


function moveAndResize(index){
    var item = $('.work-showcase:eq('+index+')');
    $('.work-showcase').animate({height:'135px'}, 500);
  $(item).animate({height:'400px'}, 500,function() {  
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(item).offset().top });  
  });
}
```

This works as long as the indexes are the same. If you want the index of the buttons to be different, add an id tag or something else that you can then pass to the moveAndResize which maps to the index of the item you want to change.